# In nodejs, how can I read a CSV header first but still handle the rest of the file asynchronously

Tags: node.js, csv, asynchronous, user-input

I want to read in a csv file, but based on the headers I want to query input from the user ('Is this column a string or a number column?').
This means that the routine is 'doubly' asynchronous; reading the stream and querying the user while processing the header row.

The libraries I've seen so far do not make it possible to handle the header row asynchronously or I'm missing something.

How could I implement this without having to reimplement the csv logic myself.

```
let csvHeader = null
fs.createReadStream(path)
    .pipe(csv_parse({ delimiter }))
    .on('data', function (csvrow) {
        //do something with csvrow
        if (csvHeader === null) {
            //handle header asynchronously
            csvHeader = ....
        } else {
            //handle row
        }
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        ....
```

Comment: Did you try `csv-stream`? It has a special `header` event. See on their `README.md`.

Comment: I checked if, but the 'on header' function does not have a callback in the signature, so it isn't asynchronous